# Is there any meaning behind the letters "GMO" in this scene in "Brahms: The Boy II"?

Tags: brahms-the-boy-ii

I was watching "Brahms: The Boy II" when I noticed some letters somehow hidden in a scene.

The shot is from 00:41:02.

[image]

Here is an improved version:

[image]

Comment: At the very least this is GMOO and looks like part of a larger word.

Comment: IDK, maybe OMG in reverse? I'm out of ideas...